# Targeting specific DIV element for .animate()

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I have 2 div elements that I want to be able to move on the screen by clicking a button.  I also want to be able to switch the active div by clicking 1 of 2 buttons.

Right now the left and right movement works, but then when I switch the active div and try to move it up or down, both div elements move together!

[image]

Please point me in the right direction, I'm lost on this one.

You can see what I am working with here:
https://jsfiddle.net/jkries/x1k5yLrf/1/

Thanks for any advice.

```js
       var playerTarget;
       $(document).ready(function() {
           $('#pickPlayer1').click(function() {
               playerTarget = '#player1';
           });
           $('#pickPlayer2').click(function() {
               playerTarget = '#player2';
           });

           //Movement scripts
           $('#moveLeft').click(function() {
               $(playerTarget).animate({
                   'marginLeft' : "-=30px" //moves left
               });
           });
           $('#moveRight').click(function() {
               $(playerTarget).animate({
                   'marginLeft' : "+=30px" //moves right
               });
           });
           $('#moveDown').click(function() {
               $(playerTarget).animate({
                   'marginTop' : "+=30px" //moves down
               });
           });
           $('#moveUp').click(function() {
               $(playerTarget).animate({
                   'marginTop' : "-=30px" //moves up
               });
           });
       });
```

```html
<body>

<button id="pickPlayer1">Player 1</button>
<button id="pickPlayer2">Player 2</button><br><br>

<button id="moveLeft">Move Left</button>
<button id="moveRight">Move right</button>
<button id="moveDown">Move Down</button>
<button id="moveUp">Move Up</button>
<hr>


Click a player to move that player:<br>

<div id="player1" style="background:#98bf21;height:80px;width:80px;position:relative;">Thing 1</div>

<div id="player2" style="background:orange;height:80px;width:80px;position:relative;">Thing 2</div>

</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with the `CSS`, the elements depend on each other right now. So when you set, let's say, `margin-top` to the first square, it pushes the other down, and inverse. Change `position: relative;` to `position: absolute;` and it will work.

Updated **[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/x1k5yLrf/2/)**.

See the working snippet below:

```js
var playerTarget;
       $(document).ready(function() {
           $('#pickPlayer1').click(function() {
               playerTarget = '#player1';
               
           });
           $('#pickPlayer2').click(function() {
               playerTarget = '#player2';
           });

           //Movement scripts
           $('#moveLeft').click(function() {
               $(playerTarget).animate({
                   'marginLeft' : "-=30px" //moves left
               });
           });
           $('#moveRight').click(function() {
               $(playerTarget).animate({
                   'marginLeft' : "+=30px" //moves right
               });
           });
           $('#moveDown').click(function() {
               $(playerTarget).animate({
                   'marginTop' : "+=30px" //moves down
               });
           });
           $('#moveUp').click(function() {
               $(playerTarget).animate({
                   'marginTop' : "-=30px" //moves up
               });
           });
       });
```

```css
#player2{
  top: 200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>

<button id="pickPlayer1">Player 1</button>
<button id="pickPlayer2">Player 2</button><br><br>

<button id="moveLeft">Move Left</button>
<button id="moveRight">Move right</button>
<button id="moveDown">Move Down</button>
<button id="moveUp">Move Up</button>
<hr>


Click a player to move that player:<br>

<div id="player1" style="background:#98bf21;height:80px;width:80px; position: absolute;">Thing 1</div>

<div id="player2" style="background:orange;height:80px;width:80px; position: absolute;">Thing 2</div>

</body>
```

Or another way, if you want to keep the relative position, is to use `top, bottom, right, left` instead of `margin` when you move the elements:

```js
var playerTarget;
       $(document).ready(function() {
           $('#pickPlayer1').click(function() {
               playerTarget = '#player1';
               
           });
           $('#pickPlayer2').click(function() {
               playerTarget = '#player2';
           });

           //Movement scripts
           $('#moveLeft').click(function() {
               $(playerTarget).animate({
                   'left' : "-=30px" //moves left
               });
           });
           $('#moveRight').click(function() {
               $(playerTarget).animate({
                   'left' : "+=30px" //moves right
               });
           });
           $('#moveDown').click(function() {
               $(playerTarget).animate({
                   'top' : "+=30px" //moves down
               });
           });
           $('#moveUp').click(function() {
               $(playerTarget).animate({
                   'top' : "-=30px" //moves up
               });
           });
       });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>

<button id="pickPlayer1">Player 1</button>
<button id="pickPlayer2">Player 2</button><br><br>

<button id="moveLeft">Move Left</button>
<button id="moveRight">Move right</button>
<button id="moveDown">Move Down</button>
<button id="moveUp">Move Up</button>
<hr>


Click a player to move that player:<br>

<div id="player1" style="background:#98bf21;height:80px;width:80px; position: relative;">Thing 1</div>

<div id="player2" style="background:orange;height:80px;width:80px; position: relative;">Thing 2</div>

</body>
```